# Redirect subdomain, but only if site root requested

Tags: mod-rewrite

I can't seem to find an answer to this specific question:

How can I forward `http://play.domain.com` -- but NOT `http://play.domain.com/xxx`

To:
`http://work.domain.com`

Where "xxx" is any string.

In other words, if the user requests the site root, redirect, otherwise stay on the chosen URL.

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !work.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://work.domain.com.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it's not doing anything :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !work.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://work.domain.com.com/ [R=301,L]
```

to only redirect the blank request.

Comment: Breaks when there are other subdomains besides "play"

Comment: @JonLin Are you sure about that? Did you not mean to put this comment on anubhava's answer?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: It might not impact you today but in future if you have another subdomain `game.domain.com` this rule will redirect even that to `http://work.domain.com/`.

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt The condition only checks if the domain is *not* `work.domain.com`. That means if there's another subdomain: `foo.domain.com`, that is separate from the play->work redirect thing, then it will also get redirected since it's not `work.domain.com`.

Comment: @JonLin Ah, I see what you mean. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^play\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://work.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You might consider showing rewrite rule as `RewriteRule ^/?$ https://work.domain.com [R=301,L]` (note added `/?` in match pattern).  This would allow rule to be used in both apache conf as well as .htaccess context. Also I would suggest removing Options configurations from your answer as this has nothing to do with the rewrite.

Comment: @MikeBrant: Agreed, implemented both of your suggestions. Thanks.